# How to quote poetry and other multi-line texts?

Tags: support

This is just so there's something I can link to on the meta when this issue comes up.

Is it possible to quote multi-line text on the Stack Exchange software?

Comment: Might be worth editing this to cover how to do multi-line spoiler blocks (which people tend to have rather more trouble with).

Comment: @Randal'Thor I made the answer community wiki, so feel free to edit that information in. (aka I don't know how to do multiline spoiler blockquotes, I tried and failed miserably).

Comment: (BTW, you can always link to the [editing help](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/editing-help).)

Comment: @Mithrandir actually I can't, because the editing help page doesn't explain how to do multi-line quotes.

Answer (score 11):

Yes it is. Put **two spaces at the end of each line** and it will work.

For example, the following code will create a multi-line quote. Highlight the code with your mouse to see the spaces at the end of each line.

```
> That corpse you planted last year in your garden,  
Has it begun to sprout? Will it bloom this year?  
Or has the sudden frost disturbed its bed?  
Oh keep the Dog far hence, that’s friend to men,  
Or with his nails he’ll dig it up again!
```

Here's what that code outputs:

> That corpse you planted last year in your garden,
>   Has it begun to sprout? Will it bloom this year?
>   Or has the sudden frost disturbed its bed?
>   Oh keep the Dog far hence, that’s friend to men,
>   Or with his nails he’ll dig it up again!

---

In fact, the same works for **spoiler** blocks, although in this context you also have to put two spaces at the end of each *blank* line as well as each line of text. For example, the following code (as before, highlight to see the double spaces) ...

```
>! At the end of Shakespeare's Hamlet,  
>! which was a very good play,  
>!  
>! nearly everyone dies.
```

... produces the following output:

> At the end of Shakespeare's Hamlet,
>  which was a very good play,
>
>  nearly everyone dies.

Comment: I tend to use a line-break in multi-line spoiler blocks <br>.

Comment: Nnnnnooooo you spoiled _Hamlet_ for meeeee